# mysql SELECT FROM two tables and LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

I have problem with select from two tables and left join to third. Query:

```
SELECT 
    c.id AS currency, u.user, us.enabled AS currency 
FROM 
    users AS u, 
    currency AS c
    LEFT JOIN users_settings AS us ON(c.id=us.currency, u.user=us.user)
WHERE 
    c.off=0 AND c.disabled=0 AND c.status=1
```

Error:

> `#1054` - Unknown column 'u.user' in 'field list'

I need Cartesian product of users and currency. 
Users: id, login, email, pass

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product

Comment: Can you show us the users table?

Comment: Don't use comma-join syntax, and definitely don't mix comma-join and explicit join syntax together until you really know what you're doing.

Comment: I need Cartesian product of users and currency. Users: id, login, email, pass http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product

Answer (score 5):

You are mixing explicit and implicit join syntax.  Try this:

```
SELECT c.id AS currency, u.user, us.enabled AS currency
FROM currency AS c LEFT JOIN
     users_settings AS us
     ON c.id = us.currency LEFT JOIN
     users u
     on u.user = us.user
WHERE c.off = 0 AND c.disabled = 0 AND c.status = 1 ;
```

MySQL does not necessarily allow the fields to be known over a `,`.  Scoping is one of the differences between `,` and `cross join`.  In any case, though, you should use a separate `on` clause for each `join`.

Here is the description in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html):

> INNER JOIN and , (comma) are semantically equivalent in the absence of
>   a join condition: both produce a Cartesian product between the
>   specified tables (that is, each and every row in the first table is
>   joined to each and every row in the second table).
>
> However, the precedence of the comma operator is less than of INNER
>   JOIN, CROSS JOIN, LEFT JOIN, and so on. If you mix comma joins with
>   the other join types when there is a join condition, an error of the
>   form Unknown column 'col_name' in 'on clause' may occur. Information
>   about dealing with this problem is given later in this section.

Instead of trying to really understand what this means, just avoid using `,` in the `from` clause.  It is not ever needed.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not cartesian product http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product

Comment: @Sannin . . . A `,` is semantically equivalent to `cross join` except for the scoping rules.  Both create a Cartesian product without additional filtering.  The point, though, is that the syntax of using a `,` is causing the problem with the query.

Comment: Confirmed @GordonLinoff reply. Instead `from tableA, tableB, tableC` replace with multiple left join `from tableA left join tableB left join tableC`